# Duplicate data in database after crawling

Tags: php

I am using simple html dom to crawl data from a site into my database and display on my web page. But every time i run the file, duplicate data is also inserted into database.How can i keep check on whether data is already present in database or not? Here is my file for crawling:

```
 <?php

 $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","crawling");\

 mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "")or die("cannot connect"); 
 mysql_select_db("crawling")or die("cannot select DB");


 include "domcrawl.php";
 $url="http://www.bgr.in/category/reviews/";
 $html=file_get_html($url);
 //$arr=$html->find('table[class=findList] tbody tr td[class=result_text]');
 $m=$html->find('img');

 $b=$html->find('a');

 $c=$html->find('p');  

 $imghead = $b[21]->innertext;

 $img = $m[3];

 $imgtext = $c[0];


 $sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO image1
 ( head, image, text, name)
 VALUES
 ( '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')",

 mysql_real_escape_string($imghead),
 mysql_real_escape_string($img),
 mysql_real_escape_string($imgtext),
mysql_real_escape_string("gm")
);
 mysql_query($sql);





 $sql = "SELECT head FROM image1 WHERE name='gm'";
 $sql1 = "SELECT image FROM image1 WHERE name='gm'";
 $sql2 = "SELECT text FROM image1 WHERE name='gm'";
 $result = mysql_query("$sql");
 $result1 = mysql_query("$sql1");
 $result2 = mysql_query("$sql2");

  $head_get= mysql_result($result, 0);
 $img_get= mysql_result($result1, 0);
 $text_get= mysql_result($result2, 0);
 echo "<br><br>";

 echo $head_get;
 echo "<br><br>";
 echo $img_get;
 echo $text_get;


  ?>
```

Comment: What is your code supposed to do? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Because there isn't a tag named `pubDate` anywhere in the XML document you're trying to parse.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12769983/2209007) is sufficiently similar to figure out what that error would mean.

Comment: Use isset. Check if value is set for the node.

Comment: So first you are going to store it in an array, just to store it in mysql.. why not skip the array bit ? o.O

Answer (score 1):

Must check before getting object properties, In your case it is finding empty object

```
$link = $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0);
if(!empty($link)){
 $nodeValue = $link->nodeValue,
}

'link' => $nodeValue;
```

Similarly do for all

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue` is line 11, there seems to be no element with tag `pubDate`, which is why `$node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)` returns either `null` or `false`.